# How to convert String to Date in php?

Tags: php, date

I trying to get a date in the `d/m/Y H:i` format. Here's my code

```
$dateStr = "28/07/2016 10:00";
echo date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($dateStr));
```

Here's the ouput:

```
01/01/1970 01:00
```

I trying to convert to other formats, but the result still the same date. I know this kind of obvious but still can't understand why i'm getting that date as result.

Comment: why you don't want to use standart [`DateTime.createfromformat`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php) or [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php)?

Comment: Isn't your string already in that format? Also you don't need to convert yoru string twice into a timestamp.

Comment: you did it so now what you want @abff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and it's [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method to parse the string to date in required format.

Like this,

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', "28/07/2016 10:00");
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $date;
```

Comment: Why is there [date_create_from_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) considered procedural-style?

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code

```
$dateStr = "28/07/2016 10:00";
$dateStr =str_replace("/","-",$dateStr);
echo date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($dateStr));
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code they posted in their question

Comment: just add one line $dateStr =str_replace("/","-",$dateStr);

Answer (score 0):

This code achieves what you want to do:

```
$dateString = '28/07/2016 10:00';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $dateString);
echo($date->format('d/m/Y H:i'));
```